# phpMyAdmin - Display all queries

Tags: 12.10, display, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have installed a fresh desktop with ubuntu quantal and the following packages versions:

> MySQL: 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.10.1
>   Apache: 2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
>   phpMyAdmin: 3.4.11.1deb1

I would like phpmyadmin to display all the queries I run. How can I do it?

Thank you very much.

UPDATE
To be more specific, there are some queries showing into the query box, but I would like phpMyAdmin to show ALL of them including when I export a Database (if possible). Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this question is better suited at Stackoverflow.com

Comment: Are you looking for a kind of MySQL query history?

Comment: In previous versions of phpMyAdmin, everytime you launched an event (i.e. create a user) you could see the query launched displayed. I do not see it displayed anymore and that is what I would like to get. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you see all the queries that you put into the textarea in the "SQL" tab.
Check out if it works for you on the [PHPMyAdmin demo site](http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/STABLE), currently running v3.5.3 (Login: root/no password). If it doesn't help, try describing precisely what you do. Maybe the extended AJAX functions in newer releases prevent the display of certain queries.

Also, there's a history function ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3247676/283854)):

> phpmyadmin does offer a brief history. If you click on the 'sql' icon
>   just underneath the 'phpmyadmin' logo, it'll open a new window. In the
>   new window, just click on the 'history' tab.

EDIT: Downgrading phpmyadmin to **version 3.2.x** should help. Back then, less or none AJAX functions were applied to the query text input.

BTW: I prefer [Adminer](http://www.adminer.org/) to PHPMyAdmin for a few month now. Added solution

Comment: Have you tried the demo page? It brings a lot of warnings and does not login. Adminer might be a great tool, but it is not straight forward to a non programmer. In my case, all I did was to install a lamp server by "sudo tasksel install lamp-server" and tried to use phpMyAdmin right after. It was then to my surprise that the SQL queries were not showing. By the way, the SQL history tab undeneath the phpmyadmin logo does not show the history either. As I mentioned before, it has not happened to me in previous installations.

Comment: The demo works fine in my FF15 (on Win7). I assume it all might be a problem with your browser.

Comment: I guess downgrading phpmyadmin to version 3.2.x could help. Back then, all the elaborate AJAX stuff wasn't applied to the query text input.

Comment: Downgrading helped; however, the weird things is that afterwards I upgraded again and it worked fine. Probably, something went really wrong on the first install. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to have a look at the [MySQL Query Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-log.html) rather than phpMyAdmin

Comment: It is not exactly what I am looking for. In previous versions of phpMyAdmin, everytime you launched an event (i.e. create a user) you could see the query launched displayed. I do not see it displayed anymore and that is what I would like to get. Thank you.